# Methods behind qgis:simplifygeometries and qgis:smoothgeometry?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, simplify, smoothing

I would like to know on which method (e.g. Douglas-Peucker line simplification) the modules *qgis:simplifygeometries* and *qgis:smoothgeometry* are built on.

I cannot find further information on these modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplifying and smoothing operations are related to the [QgsGeometry()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html) Class: this means that you can run them when dealing with the geometry of the current feature.

As far as I know, the **Simplify geometries** algorithm literally simplifies the current geometry by reducing the number of vertices on the basis of a tolerance value (so, there isn't any particular method applied).

Instead, the **Smooth geometry** algorithm is based on the *Chaikin* algorithm, as reported in the [smooth()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#ab2f6d720b51f96686f3152a6dabfe201) module:

> *Smooths a geometry by rounding off corners using the **Chaikin**
>   algorithm.*
>
> *This operation roughly doubles the number of vertices in a geometry.*

**EDIT**

The **Simplify geometries** algorithm is based on the [simplify()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#a784f50a0c6d686ee659a437e71866dbd) module which, as brilliantly noted by [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) in its [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239684/methods-behind-qgissimplifygeometries-and-qgissmoothgeometry/239695?noredirect=1#comment374203_239695), leads to [GEOS](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/index.html). From the following links:

[geos::simplify::DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier Class Reference](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1simplify_1_1DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier.html)

[geos::simplify::TopologyPreservingSimplifier Class Reference](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1simplify_1_1TopologyPreservingSimplifier.html)

it seems that there is an explicit reference to the *Douglas-Peucker* algorithm. More in detail, from the first link above:

> Simplifies a linestring (sequence of points) using the standard
>   ***Douglas-Peucker*** algorithm.

Comment: Isn't that method that takes out vertices on the basis of a tolerance value just this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm?

Comment: @user30184 I sincerely don't know. I have seen the code and the `simplify()` module is used, but its [documentation](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#a784f50a0c6d686ee659a437e71866dbd) is a bit vague.

Comment: Links lead to GEOS and this http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1simplify_1_1DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier.html and this http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1simplify_1_1TopologyPreservingSimplifier.html talk about Douglas-Peucker. I would say you can safely edit your answer to mention it.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for this add! I think you are right and I will properly edit my answer for adding this information.